# Share queue in event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Is it possible to share an asyncio.Queue over different tasks in one event loop?

**The usecase:**

Two tasks are publishing data on a queue, and one task is grabbing the new items from the Queue. All tasks in an asynchronous way.

main.py

```
import asyncio
import creator


async def pull_message(queue):
    while True:
        # Here I dont get messages, maybe the queue is always
        # occupied by a other task? 
        msg = await queue.get()
        print(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__"
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(pull_message(queue))

    creators = list()
    for i in range(2):
        creators.append(loop.create_task(cr.populate_msg(queue)))

    # add future to creators for easy handling
    creators.append(future)
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*creators))
```

creator.py

```
import asyncio

async def populate_msg(queue):
    while True:
        msg = "Foo"
        await queue.put(msg)
```

Comment: Yes - the whole point of the queue is that it can be shared by multiple tasks. Can you show the code that doesn't work like you'd like it to?

Comment: I added some code to clarify what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `populate_msg` doesn't yield to the event loop because the queue is unbounded. This is somewhat counter-intuitive because the coroutine clearly contains an `await`, but that `await` only suspends the execution of the coroutine if the coroutine would otherwise block. Since `put()` on an unbounded queue never blocks, `populate_msg` is the only thing executed by the event loop.

The problem will go away once you change `populate_msg` to actually do something else (like await a network event). For testing purposes you can add `await asyncio.sleep(0)` inside the loop, which will force the coroutine to yield control to the event loop at every iteration of the `while` loop. Note that this will cause the event loop to spend an entire core by continuously spinning the loop.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a other approach get rid of the sleep? Because as you said, it is adding overhead to add a sleep.

Comment: @loose11 `sleep(0)` is only suggested for testing purposes. In production code `populate_msg` would produce the messages based on an external source, and that would where the real awaiting would occur. If that is not the case, then please add more information about your actual use case.